# How can I find out what features the total score returned from products is based on on Solr?

Tags: search, solr, boosting, solr8

How can I find out what features the total score returned from products is based on on Solr? I'll print these scores one by one elsewhere.

I want to see what the total scores of the products returned from Solr are based on.

Comment: Have you tried appending `debug=all` to your query and looking at the output? It will give a detailed explanation of how the score was calculated for a specific document.

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html